# Insert unique value multiple times depending on variable column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have the following columns in my table:

```
PromotionID | NumberOfCodes 
1             10
2             5
```

I need to insert the `PromotionID` into a new SQL table a number of times - depending on the value in `NumberOfCodes`.

So given the above, my result set should read:

```
PromotionID 
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
```

Comment: Seems easy enough... What have you already tried? Please read [ask] and the first couple of paragraphs in the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What's the max number `NumberOfCodes` could be?

Comment: Hi Zohar - I've been directed towards nested loops, but not much experience with these.

Comment: Hi Larnu - could be up to 20,000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need recursive cte :

```
with r_cte as (
     select t.PromotionID, 1 as start, NumberOfCodes 
     from table t
     union all
     select id, start + 1, NumberOfCodes 
     from r_cte 
     where start < NumberOfCodes 
)
insert into table (PromotionID)
  select PromotionID
  from r_cte 
  order by PromotionID;
```

Default recursion level 100, use query hint `option(maxrecursion 0)` if you have NumberOfCodes more.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh - this gives me exactly what I need

Comment: FYI, @BenW2811 if your max number *is* 20,000 then performance won't be as good as it good be. An rCTE, as it's name suggests, is recursive, and SQL is awful at recursive things. It excels at set based methods

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a tally for such things. Once you start getting to larger row sets, the performance of an rCTe degrades very quickly:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --Up to 100 rows. Add more cross joins to N for more rows
SELECT YT.PromotionID
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON YT.NumberOfCodes >= T.I;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a recursive common table expression to generate the rows from the source table, that you can then insert in the target table:

```
with cte as (
    select promotion_id, number_of_codes n from sourcetable 
    union all select promotion_id, n - 1 from mytable where n > 1
)
insert into targettable (promotion_id)
select promotion_id from cte
```